# Printing Using USB cable issue

Tags: java, android, printing

I am using following code to print through android device with USB cable attached to my Samsung printer.

When use `startPrinting` method it give me following verification in debugging log:

1. Command to printer sent successfully
2. Permission from printer granted.

and the printer even starts beeping, but the data I provide does not get printed. I am stuck at this stage and have found no help from google or on stackoverflow either.

**Note: There is no crash no error either**

**I am testing this code on Android Jelly bean 4.3 OS**

Any help would be appreciated.

```
private UsbManager mUsbManager;
private UsbDevice mDevice;
private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
private UsbInterface mInterface;
private UsbEndpoint mEndPoint;
private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private static Boolean forceCLaim = true;

HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mDeviceList;
Iterator<UsbDevice> mDeviceIterator;

int protocol;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mDeviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        mDeviceIterator = mDeviceList.values().iterator();

        Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrint);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Device List Size: " + String.valueOf(mDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usbDevice);
        String usbDevice = "";
        // This is just testing what devices are connected
        while (mDeviceIterator.hasNext())
            {
                UsbDevice usbDevice1 = mDeviceIterator.next();
                usbDevice += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceId() + "\n" + "DeviceName: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceName() + "\n" + "DeviceClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                        + translateDeviceClass(usbDevice1.getDeviceClass()) + "\n" + "DeviceSubClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n" + "VendorID: " + usbDevice1.getVendorId() + "\n" + "ProductID: " + usbDevice1.getProductId()
                        + "\n";

                protocol = usbDevice1.getDeviceProtocol();

                int interfaceCount = usbDevice1.getInterfaceCount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE COUNT: " + String.valueOf(interfaceCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mDevice = usbDevice1;

                if (mDevice == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "mDevice is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        // Toast.makeText(this, "mDevice is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                textView.setText(usbDevice);
            }

        if (mDevice == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "mDevice is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        else
            {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "mDevice is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
                        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
                        if (mDevice != null)
                            mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
                        // else
                        // Toast.makeText(this, "USB ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // print(mConnection, mInterface);
                    }
            });
    }

private String translateDeviceClass(int deviceClass)
    {
        switch (deviceClass)
            {
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_APP_SPEC:
                return "Application specific USB class";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO:
                return "USB class for audio devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA:
                return "USB class for CDC devices (communications device class)";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_COMM:
                return "USB class for communication devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC:
                return "USB class for content security devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CSCID:
                return "USB class for content smart card devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID:
                return "USB class for human interface devices (for example, mice and keyboards)";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB:
                return "USB class for USB hubs";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE:
                return "USB class for mass storage devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MISC:
                return "USB class for wireless miscellaneous devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE:
                return "USB class indicating that the class is determined on a per-interface basis";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PHYSICA:
                return "USB class for physical devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER:
                return "USB class for printers";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_STILL_IMAGE:
                return "USB class for still image devices (digital cameras)";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC:
                return "Vendor specific USB class";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VIDEO:
                return "USB class for video devices";
            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER:
                return "USB class for wireless controller devices";
            default:
                return "Unknown USB class!";
            }
    }

// Broadcast receiver to obtain permission from user for connection
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
                    {
                        synchronized (this)
                            {
                                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                                    {
                                        if (device != null)
                                            {
                                                // call method to set up device communication
                                                mInterface = device.getInterface(0);
                                                mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(0);
                                                mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

                                                Log.i("Info", "Device permission granted");
                                                startPrinting(device);

                                                // setup();
                                            }
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        // Log.d("SUB", "permission denied for device " + device);
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THIS DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    };

public void startPrinting(final UsbDevice printerDevice)
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                UsbDeviceConnection conn;
                UsbInterface usbInterface;

                @Override
                public void run()
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                Log.i("Info", "Bulk transfer started");
                                // usbInterface = printerDevice.getInterface(0);

                                for (int i = 0; i < printerDevice.getInterfaceCount(); i++)
                                    {
                                        usbInterface = printerDevice.getInterface(i);

                                        if (usbInterface.getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER)
                                            {
                                                // usbInterface = mDevice;
                                            }
                                    }

                                UsbEndpoint endPoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0);
                                conn = mUsbManager.openDevice(mDevice);
                                conn.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);

                                String myStringData = "TEXT";
                                myStringData += "\n";
                                byte[] array = myStringData.getBytes();
                                ByteBuffer output_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(array.length);
                                UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
                                request.initialize(conn, endPoint);
                                request.queue(output_buffer, array.length);
                                if (conn.requestWait() == request)
                                    {
                                        Log.i("Info", output_buffer.getChar(0) + "");
                                        Message m = new Message();
                                        m.obj = output_buffer.array();
                                        output_buffer.clear();
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        Log.i("Info", "No request recieved");
                                    }
                                int transfered = conn.bulkTransfer(endPoint, myStringData.getBytes(), myStringData.getBytes().length, 5000);
                                Log.i("Info", "Amount of data transferred : " + transfered);

                            }
                        catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.e("Exception", "Unable to transfer bulk data");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        finally
                            {
                                try
                                    {
                                        conn.releaseInterface(usbInterface);
                                        Log.i("Info", "Interface released");
                                        conn.close();
                                        Log.i("Info", "Usb connection closed");
                                        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
                                        Log.i("Info", "Brodcast reciever unregistered");
                                    }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Log.e("Exception", "Unable to release resources because : " + e.getMessage());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }

                    }
            });
    }

private void print(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbInterface intrface)
    {
        String test = "THIS IS A PRINT TEST";
        // String text = "#move " + protocol + ";" + "#print" + test;
        // Log.e("text", text);
        byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes();

        if (intrface == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        if (connection == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        if (forceCLaim == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "FORCE CLAIM IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        connection.claimInterface(intrface, forceCLaim);
        connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, testBytes.length, 0);

        connection.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this exact behavior from other operating systems, when the printer manufacturer uses a proprietary (and non disclosed :-( ) protocol over the USB bus. Specifically, the HP Laserjet P1060 series comes to mind. Both with GNU/Linux and Mac OS-X, the OS discoveres the printer quite well, and tries to print using a generic driver (e.g. HP Laserjet II). The printer's LED starts flashing - but nothing comes out. This felt a little as if some command was missing to make the printer actually print the page.

In these cases, a proprietary firmware blob needed to be downloaded to make things work. Unfortunately, it may be difficult to find such a driver for Android for home/small business printer models. I have had some luck with the Samsung Mobile Print Application (http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile-print-app/) with departamental networked laser printers (ML 3471-ND and suchlike). This was over Wifi + Ethernet.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

From your description everything seems to work - data transfer is happening, there are no errors but printing is not producing anything. Possibly because the Samsung printer is a page printer and the code you have is good for line-printing (Pos printers and Dot Matrix). In such a case the data will reside in the print buffer waiting for the page to be completed. Try to force a page to complete by issuing a formfeed and check.